# Error in projection from a DXF file

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, layers, dxf

I have imported a .dxf file created in Autocad into QGIS interface over an OpenStreetMap raster layer base map. They are both in ETRS89 and I am trying to make them match by modifying SRC of both layers, but they are always like 200 meters displaced. In this image, both layers are in ETRS89 / EPSG 25831 projection.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a datum transformation issue. You need to provide more details on your data source(s) and processing steps.

Comment: It is a base map from OpenStreetMap and a vectorial layer created on Autocad, imported as a .dxf file. They are both in ETRS89 projection, but still have this deviation.

Comment: Yes, that makes it a datum transformation issue. Please [Edit] the question to contain exact details of the spatial reference lineage of the DXF and basemap.